# Can't download a file using selenium-chromedriver on javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to download a file using selenium, specifically the linux .deb version of [protonmail bridge found here.](https://proton.me/mail/bridge) I'm using selenium to do this because I want to always download the latest file version, but direct links contain the version number so I have to use the website to direct me to the latest version.

I've gotten everything working except for confirming and starting the download.  The closest I can get is creating a `.crdownload` file, which might indicate that the file isn't finishing downloading.  I'm very sure this isn't my case though because the file is only around 70MB and I've waited as long as 90 seconds for it to finish but it just sits there.

I've tried many combinations of preferences and arguments, and have been researching this a lot but I can't find any settings that aren't already in my code.  I'm using the [selenium grid chrome docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome) so I know this isn't a mixup with my chromedriver and chrome version.  I'm using selenium-webdriver@4.15.0 on my machine and chrome 119.0.0 in the docker image.

Maybe I've just been looking for too long, here's my code I appreciate any insight given:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until, Capabilities } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
// require('chromedriver'); 

async function downloadForLinux() {
    console.log('Initializing the Chrome driver...')
    let prefs = {
        "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": false,
        "safebrowsing.disable_download_protection": true,
        "download.directory_upgrade": true,
        "download.default_directory": '/home/seluser',
        "download.prompt_for_download": false,
        // "download.mime_types": "application/octet-stream",
        "browser.set_download_behavior": "allow"
    }
    let options = new chrome.Options()
        .addArguments('--enable-javascript')
        // .addArguments('--disable-gpu')
        // .addArguments('--no-sandbox')
        // .addArguments('--headless=new')
        .addArguments('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
        // .addArguments('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection')
        // .addArguments('--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist')
        .setUserPreferences(prefs);
    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .usingServer('http://localhost:4444')
        .withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome())
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();

    try {
        console.log('Going to the URL...')
        await driver.get('https://proton.me/mail/bridge'); 

        console.log('Finding the download button...')
        const downloadLinuxButton = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Download for Linux')]")), 10000);
        await downloadLinuxButton.click();

        console.log('Waiting for the .deb download button...')
        const downloadDebButton = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Download (.deb)')]")), 10000);
        await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(downloadDebButton), 10000);
        await downloadDebButton.click();
        
        // console.log('Waiting for download prompt...');
        // await driver.wait(until.alertIsPresent(), 10000);
        // driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

        console.log('Waiting for download to finish...');
        await driver.sleep(60000);

    } finally {
        await driver.quit();
    }
}

downloadForLinux().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: don't quit the driver until that download directory no longer has any *.crdownload files in it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with seleniumbasic (its what i have installed already and i guess its close enough)

```
Dim driver As New WebDriver

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    driver.Start "Chrome"
    driver.Get "https://proton.me/mail/bridge"
    
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Linux')]").Click
    
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Download (.deb)')]").Click
End Sub
```

This seems to work it downloads the .deb file to my download directory.

Comment: i'll try setting it up with JS now